# Why Erlang sasl application doesn't save my log files correctly?

Tags: erlang, error-logging, sasl, erlang-shell

I booted the Erlang shell with sasl started and with the following configuration file, but it doesn't create an error log on disk:

```
%% rotating log and minimal tty
[{sasl, [
 {sasl_error_logger, false},    
 %% define the parameters of the rotating log
 %% the log file directory
 {error_logger_mf_dir,"ErrorLogger/erLog"}, 
     %% # bytes per logfile
 {error_logger_mf_maxbytes,10485760}, % 10 MB
     %% maximum number of logfiles
 {error_logger_mf_maxfiles, 10}
]}].
```

However if I place `"."` as the directory value, it creates unnamed logs on disk: `{error_logger_mf_dir,"."}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must provide absolute or relative address for `error_logger_mf_dir` config.

**Absolute:**

```
 %% the log file absolute directory
 {error_logger_mf_dir,"/path/to/ErrorLogger/erLog"},
```

**Relative:**

```
 %% the log file based on current directory
 {error_logger_mf_dir,"./ErrorLogger/erLog"}, 
 %% Also it must work
 {error_logger_mf_dir,"ErrorLogger/erLog"},
```

**Note:** Make sure that your Erlang application has write access to `ErrorLogger/erLog` directory. If so `sasl` will create there one file called index, and report files 1, 2, 3 and so on which should be browsed by the [Report Browser (rb)](http://erlang.org/doc/man/rb.html) tool.

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!!